# consume SOAP web service with spring mvc

Tags: spring, web-services

I new to SOAP web service. In my project there is a requirement where I need to consume the SOAP web service in spring MVC. I tried search in google I am not getting simple example to integrate the SOAP services with spring MVC.

I have few other question as well.

1. What is JAXB? As per my understanding the JAXB is used for marshalling and unmarshalling the objects from service.

2.Whether I can use both restful web service and SOAP web service together in same spring mvc application?

3.What is different between Spring-WS and JAX-WS?

Comment: bharathi: Did the below answer help ?

Comment: sorry for delay reply. I have accepted your answer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is JAXB? As per my understanding the JAXB is used for marshalling
>   and unmarshalling the objects ?

Yes, JAXB is a framework which can be used to convert Java object into an XML file (stream) and vice versa.

Java Object to an XML file conversion is called  marshalling and the opposite is unmarshalling.

This technique will be useful when two applications are exchanging the business data using XML.

> 2.Whether I can use both restful web service and SOAP web service together in same spring mvc application ?

Yes, you can use both together with in the same project as per your business requirements.

For example, assume that your application (project) might need some data from two external sources i.e., external system1 (assume that it exposes it's endpoints in SOAP) and 
external system2 (assume that it exposes it's endpoints in REST), your application has to interact with both of those to exchange the data.

Similarly your application might need to expose few services in REST and few services in SOAP (assume that the other system can consume only SOAP), it is all about agreeing between different systems on data exchanging formats.

> 3.What is the difference between Spring-WS and JAX-WS ?

`JAX-WS` is a specification & implementation built into JDK for consuming/producing SOAP services.

`Spring-WS` is a Spring API for consuming/producing SOAP services.

There are **two types of SOAP frameworks** available for the development of projects:

**Compliant to JAX-WS**  - like Apache CXF, Apache Axis2, etc..

**Non compliant to JAX-WS**  - Spring-WS

You can look at [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_frameworks) for the list of web service frameworks